# How to solve "The WebHook verification request must contain a 'code' query parameter." in an ASP.NET WebHook receiver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webhooks

I'm implemeting [Paddle WebHooks](https://vendors.paddle.com/webhook-alert-test) in my ASP.NET application. I've tried running the sample WebHook request to https://requestb.in/ and it worked perfectly (receiver returned 200). Here's the screenshot:[image: WebHooks receiver response]

Now, I tried using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/11/20/using-asp-net-webhooks-with-ifttt-and-zapier-to-monitor-twitter-and-google-sheets/) tutorial to create a WebHooks receiver in my ASP.NET application with this code:

```
public class PaddleWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public PaddleWebHookHandler()
    {
        Receiver = "genericjson";
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

The [Paddle WebHooks](https://vendors.paddle.com/webhook-alert-test) sender throws a 400 Bad Request error with this message:

> The WebHook verification request must contain a 'code' query parameter.

Do you know what's the problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a `WebHookReceiver`. The `await EnsureValidCode(request, id);` required a "code" parameter to be passed in for some strange reason.

Removing the line is enough for the problem to go away.

Comment: It required a code token because normally in a WebHook, you'd want to implement a secret to prevent someone from maliciously using the hook.  You can specify the `code` in your Web.Config, if you followed the walkthrough from MSFT here.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/11/20/using-asp-net-webhooks-with-ifttt-and-zapier-to-monitor-twitter-and-google-sheets/